# Android Facebook SDK, how to open session without login form

Tags: android, facebook, graph

I'm developing and Android app where I would like to show the posts of a Facebook Page without any login of the user. I've tried the Graph API but it always require a user login to get an access token. How I can get the posts without an user login?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

well... facebook data is all about "user", therefore you always need valid access_token

there are few exceptions though,
for example, you can display user profile picture without token,
see example; https://graph.facebook.com/100001789213579/picture?type=large

You may use your application access token for this which may be one of:

- `YOUR_APP_ID|YOUR_APP_SECRET`
- Application Access Token received from `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token? client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET& grant_type=client_credentials`

This `access_token` allow you to get any public content available via API which require `access_token`

Comment: I've seen throught Graph API Explorer that you can get the posts of a Page, but I don't know how to embedd an access_token for my own user without ask for an app user login

Comment: Thanks Gagan. It's ok but I read that facebook block api calls with api secret if the app is native/desktop. The solution is uncheck the native mode?